# IntellJ IDEA - Maven - Can't resolve OSGi bundle dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, osgi

[image]

[image]
Unresolved dependency: canapacheds-jdbm1:bundle:2.0.0-M2

how can I fix this error message? I can find this jar in maven repo, and I can successfully package my project. but IDEA keeps warning this message.

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches" and "Refresh" from Maven tool window?

Comment: @y.bedrov  yes, I do.